# Disable button if any of two text-boxes is in edit mode

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to do this via styles. But all samples are connected with validation - how to bind to "edit mode"

```
<RibbonButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="RibbonButton">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="Binding Path=(Validation.???EDIT MODE)"
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
</RibbonButton.Style>
```

Comment: If by _edit mode_ you mean focus then you have `IsKeyboardFocused` and `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` properties that you can use in your trigger. Is it what you mean by edit mode?

Comment: Is it right <Condition Binding ={"Binding Path=(Validation.IsKeyboardFocusWithin) , ElementName = textBox1}", Value="True">?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *edit mode* you mean that either `TextBox` has focus you can use [`IsKeyboardFocusWithin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithin(v=vs.110).aspx) property and trigger `IsEnabled=True` when this property is false for both `TextBox`es

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2"/>
    <RadioButton>
        <RadioButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox1, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=textBox2, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="False"/>                                
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </RadioButton.Style>
    </RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```